# Servlet applications - custom log file name in tomcat \log folder

Tags: java, servlets, java.util.logging

Am creating Java Servelet application running in tomcat. Am using `java.util.logging.logger` to capture application logs and it is storing in tomcat's `\log` folder by default name `catalina.yyyy-mm-dd`. But i want to store the logs in my custom log file name in the same tomcat's `\log` folder.

How do i can configure this ? Any idea..?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is possible to change the name of the output log file using Log4j framework.

But since you are using Java logger , i have found this official link of oracle that explains how to use the Java logger FileHandler (Configuring logging output) https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/doc.1111/e14568/handler.htm